# C# Streamreader hangs after using statement

Tags: streamreader

```
private void testbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/evemon";
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        string text;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var data = JObject.Parse(text);
        string finalized = data.ToString();
```

Im trying to parse a json response to get the string / int values out of ~6 fields, but for some reason or another the program hangs on:

```
text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

if there the line:

```
var data = JObject.Parse(text);
```

is present. The function works properly if those lines are not present (although it just prints the raw json response with the markup tags). anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you know what response do you get? I accessed that Url and all I get is some text in browser.

Comment: xml version 1.0 encoding utf-8